# C# Mvc ApiController: flexible JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am to implement a given JSON protocol in a new C# backend using Mvc ApiController. In the protocol, I have a JSON object for i18n:

```
{"settings":  [{
...
}],
"language": [{
"BACK":"Zurück",
"NAME":"Name",
"ZOOMOUT":"Verkleinern",
"CATEGORY":"Kategorie",
...
}]
}
```

The protocol's language object is extended fairly often by frontend developers. The language data will be stored in an SQL database table

```
keyword:varchar(20)
lang:varchar(2)
local:varchar(50)
```

How can I form all the data for a given language into JSON and return it, without constantly changing the underlying Model class?

Comment: Making `language` an `IDictionary<string, string>` is not working for you? It should be properly serialized at server side an available as associative array on client side.